# Comparing ratios of independent means by calculating SE difference – applicable?

Tags: variance, mean, standard-error, ratio

I am conducting a study comparing the ratio of a mean number of vocalizations to the mean number of individuals across three treatments. For each treatment, I have the mean number of vocalizations (based on 353 samples) and the mean number of individuals (based on 18 samples). Due to different time resolutions (sample duration and overlap), I cannot directly divide the original values (see sample sizes). Instead, I took a “meta-analysis approach” and I calculate the ratio value as the mean vocalizations divided by the mean individuals.

Now, I want to assess if these ratio values significantly differ among treatments. One approach I'm considering is calculating the 'SE difference' for each ratio value, using the standard errors (SE) of the means used to generate the divided value. I came across the formula from Burns and Dobson (1981), who used SEdiff to compare two means, not the ratios generated by dividing those means. Thus, I'm uncertain if this metric is suitable for my analysis.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate:

1. Comments on the validity of using the SE difference for assessing differences in ratio values between treatments and how to interpret the results.
2. Alternative suggestions for calculating confidence intervals (CI) or 'pseudo-SE' metrics for comparing two divided independent means."

Some data:
[image]

Burns, R.B., Dobson, C.B., 1981. Standard error of the difference between means, in: Burns, R.B., Dobson, C.B. (Eds.), Experimental Psychology: Research Methods and Statistics. Springer Netherlands, Dordrecht, pp. 151–157. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-7241-7_15